# Phonegap Error using XCode 9/iOS 11

Tags: ios, phonegap-build, ios11, phonegap, xcode9

Getting "No target specified for emulator. Deploying to undefined simulator Device type "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.undefined" could not be found." error while running Phonegap project using XCode 9/iOS 11. Has anyone got workaround?

Answer (score 6):

Update cordova to 4.5.0

```
cordova plugin save
npm install -g cordova
cordova platform rm ios
cordova platform add ios@4.5.0
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-console
```

Yes… cordova plugin console is now deprecated and needs to be removed. [You will get here the details](http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/09/08/ios-release.html)

Comment: worked for me without the last command: 'cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-console'